# Psql \i <file name> How to get around the permission denied error when reading from a file on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, postgresql, psql

Operating system: Windows 10
Database: Postgres 13

When trying to execute an sql file `mydatabase=>\i C:\tmp\sqlfile.sql` I get a

> C:: Permission denied

error. The file permissions have been set to read / write for all. No matter where I put the file, bin directory, public directory, tmp directory, I get the same error.

I have created a user bill and log in as Bill, and I still get the same error. The '\' has been replaced with '/' with no success. The postgres account does not work either.

Is there a system setting that needs to be set to allow Postgres to read a file?

Comment: After replacing \ with `/` what did the error message change to?

Comment: What happens if you run `type C:\tmp\sqlfile.sql` in the Windows console (not psql) right after you exited psql

Comment: With / slashes I get 'No such file or directory'.

Comment: If C:\tmp\atime.sql is entered into the Powershell the response it: 'The term 'C:\tmp\atime.sql' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.' The file does exists at that location.

Comment: Found a work around. pgAdmin 4 was used instead. Since the largest table only has 200 rows, I copied and pasted the insert statements from the file to pgAdmin. Works!